# How do I install Qt6 QtWebEngineProcess in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: qt

I installed the following packages: `qt6-base-dev`, `qt6-webengine-dev` and `libqt6webenginecore6`. But my application still returns an error: "Could not find QtWebEngineProcess". I can only find `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess` on my system.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed `libqt6webenginecore6-bin`.

Comment: Needs a reference why.